NVIDIA drivers cause significant lag in GNOME Terminal
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and noticed that the NVIDIA drivers cause significant lag in GNOME Terminal: it starts off fine, but the longer I use it, the more it lags, whether I'm entering commands directly or editing files with vim, resulting in considerable delay.
If I switch to the Nouveau driver, this issue disappears. I've tried switching between NVIDIA driver versions—550, 545, 535, 525—to no avail; the problem persists.
Oddly, apart from terminal lag, everything else works fine, making this a peculiar and frustrating issue that significantly hampers daily use.

Curios if this just started happening today or in the past few days?  This started happening to me today, and it seems to get markedly worse as I make the terminal larger (e.g. half screen or full screen).

The error appeared suddenly these two days. I've already switched to using Konsole as my terminal, and Konsole doesn't experience any lag.

I don't know who closed this question, but it is not a duplicate. This is a very specific and good question that does not relate at all with the one mentioned in the closing banner on top of this page. I have been checking in my Ubuntu 22.04 and the Nvidia drivers that work fine for my GeForce RTX 2060 are the v470.x. The versions above that, i.e. 535, 550, etc., are the ones causing problems in Gnome Terminal when I use them instead of the 470.

updating the mutter package fixed this for me
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade libmutter-10-0

(then reboot)
discussion here for reference:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/2059847
